# FB undefined while using getLoginStatus in page show

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile

I am getting FB undefined , when i write following code , i have successfully added the necessary files for facebook using  window.fbAsyncInit , the thing is if i write following code under "click" event then it works well but not at the time of pageshow in jquery mobile. this is happening might be because the facebook js files are loading bit late. but i want to check the user status on every page to restrict unnecessary or anonymous access.

```
$("#details").live( "pageshow", function() {

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and connected to your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                console.log("INSIDE ME");
              } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                //but not connected to the app
                console.log("OUTSIDE ME");
              } else {
                // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
              }
        });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the jQuery live() assignment inside the window.fbAsyncInit as well.  So that way it is only applied to the DOM element after FB has a chance to initialize.